# How to use SVG icons with linearGradient in android

Tags: android, svg

My designer gave me some icons in SVG form. And i am trying to add them to my application.

I notice that the svgs have `<lineargradient>` tags in them.

I imported these svgs via AndroidStudio -> File -> New -> Vector Assets

And as soon as I launch my app with these svgs.

Any screen that contains ImageViews that uses these SVGs immediately crashes my app. on API-23

I have a sample app here

https://github.com/liuzhen2008/whydoesntthiswork

What confuses me is that, I can see in the build generated folder, there are PNGs of many different sizes created.

Why would my app crash? I thought they just use these generated PNGs anyway.

What alternatives do I have? Are there any other tools in Android studio that allows me to quickly convert these svgs into PNGs and uses them directly?

Answer (score 0):

From my suggestion try to use  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baloons" instead of android:src="@drawable/ic_baloons".

This is your code:

```
<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baloons" />
```

Changes in your code:

```
<ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baloons"  />
```